# perform a servlet doPost from jsp form file

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm new to servlets and jsp files, and I encountered the following problem:

I have the following jsp form file:

```
<FORM action="http://myApp/register" method="post">
    <P>
    First name: <INPUT type="text" name="firstname"><BR>
    Last name: <INPUT type="text" name="lastname"><BR>
    email: <INPUT type="text" name="email"><BR>
    <INPUT type="radio" name="sex" value="Male"> Male<BR>
    <INPUT type="radio" name="sex" value="Female"> Female<BR>
    <INPUT type="submit" value="Send"> <INPUT type="reset">
    </P>
 </FORM>
```

and a servlet which handles a doPost request on the url above.
I want to give the values of the form (such as the first name and last name) to the doPost request.

Any ideas?
Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: What's the problem? Have you looked at `HttpServletRequest#getParameter(String)`?

Comment: myApp is not the same web app that is hosting your form?

Comment: Leo - it suppose to be localhost/myApp.. :)
@Sotirios Delimanolis - How I send those parameters with the post request? Can you give me an example please? and thanks for the comment!!

Comment: They're part of the form submission.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis So how can I get the value of the username for example from the servlet itself?

Comment: _Have you looked at `HttpServletRequest#getParameter(String)`?_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the parameters by their name as `request.getParameters("firstname")` to get the value of the input fields.

```
public class ServletClass extends HttpServlet {

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws    ServletException, IOException {       

    String firstName = request.getParameter("firstname");
    String lastName = request.getParameter("lastName");
   // and so on.....


   }    
}
```